How to draw a doughnut chart with labels and segments in React?
I am trying to create a doughnut chart in React similar to the one in the attached image. The chart has different segments with labels on the outside and an image inside the doughnut hole. Each segment is also color-coded.
Here is the screenshot of the chart I am trying to achieve:

I am currently using React and would appreciate guidance on which libraries or tools to use and how to implement the following features:
Segments with different colors.
Labels positioned outside the segments.
An image or any other content in the center of the doughnut.
